# Insert using bulk_create fails with an ValueError of a field name

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-shell

It is definitely different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896662/bulk-create-objects-with-many-to-many-relationship-in-django) question.

In my question the problem is that it is showing ValueError for a field that doesn't even exist 
this is my model in which i am doing bulk insert

```
class Seats(models.Model):
    seat_no = models.ManyToManyField(Snumber)
    movie_name = models.ForeignKey(Movies)
    multiplex_name = models.ForeignKey(Multiplex)
    date = models.ForeignKey(Date)
    time = models.ForeignKey(Time)

    def __str__(self):
        b = str(self.date)
        c = str(self.time)
        d = str(self.multiplex_name)
        return d+" "+b+" "+c

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('movie_name', 'multiplex_name', 'date', 'time')
        verbose_name_plural="Seats"
```

I have the single object of Movies in mov , Multiplex in mul 
And have multiple objects of Date in dt, Time in tm and Snumber in st

I want to add all objects of st in each time in tm on each date in dt with multiplex in mul and movie in mov

This is my Failed attempt to do so

```
Seats.objects.bulk_create([
        Seats(movie_name = mov,
                multiplex_name = mul,
                       seat_no = set, 
                         date = dat, 
                         time = tim
             )for dat in dt for tim in tm for set in st])
```

It is showing ValueError

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 2, in <listcomp>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 550, in __init__
    setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 499, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 476, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 783, in __init__
    (instance, self.source_field_name))
ValueError: "<Seats: Badrinath Ki Dulhania 2017-05-07 09:00:00>" needs to have a value for field "seats" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

It is telling me to set a value for field seats but i don't have any field named seats in any of my models.
What am i missing Help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk Create objects with Many to Many Relationship in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896662/bulk-create-objects-with-many-to-many-relationship-in-django)

Comment: @wrdeman my issue is different here than the question you pointed . Solution to my problem is not lying in the answer anywhere of the question you pointed. Help